# Speed up Excel file which contain VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, function, merge, cell

I am using this function in my vba:

```
Function mergedText(rngMergedCell As Range)

    If rngMergedCell.MergeCells = True Then
        mergedText = rngMergedCell.MergeArea(1, 1)
    Else
        mergedText = rngMergedCell
    End If 

End Function
```

The function let my formula to read merged cells value.
It works very well. However, the excel become so slow.

How can I speed up my excel? Please provide me with step by step answers. I am not good with vba.

Thanks!

Comment: Your function is trying to retrieve the text from a merged cell. Why? you can just point the cell and will do the same.

Comment: @Damian the function gets a reference to the top left cell of a merged range from any cell in the merged range, and returns its Value. It's only the TL cell of a MR that has the value.

Comment: yes. @chrisneilsen is right. But if you have a better formula/ways let me know. thanks!

Comment: @chrisneilsen when you merge a range it's value is the one from the top left cell in that area. Am I wrong? You can't have a merged range with multiple cells with values, everything will get deleted but the top left cell. Again, pointless to reference that.

Comment: @Damian only cell in column A has merged cells. But column B has different values. So basically i want "value A-value B' in column C.

Comment: @Damian you misunderstood me. An example: say A2:D4 is merged. `mergedText([C3])` will return the value of the merged range, which we both know is held in A2

Comment: So you don't need a vba code for this. `C2 = IF(A2 ="";A1&B2;A2&B2)` that formula will do your need.

Comment: @Damian . but the merge cell in A is not always the same. Some four rows, some 5 rows. If i use C2 = IF(A2 ="";A1&B2;A2&B2) , I have to adjust the formula everytime the no of rows in the merged cell differ

Comment: True... that brainfarted me. So your data is just column A + B in column C?

Comment: The actual formula for K89 is =IF(I89<>0,NETWORKDAYS(I89,mergedText(H89)),"")

H89 is merged from H90:H81.

by using the formula, it will straight up read H81 value

Comment: @inversebow rather than drip feeding I fo in comments,  edit your Q to include all relevant info

Comment: Are all your Merged Cells the same size?  If so, what is that?  (Also, your function only needs to contain the `mergedText = rngMergedCell.MergeArea(1, 1)` line - and, should that be `MergeArea(1,1).Value`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method to retrieve the value from Vertically Merged Cells (i.e. only 1 column), which **does not use VBA**

First, the caveat - this skips over all Blank cells in a Column, to find the first cell with data on-or-above the same row as your Target Cell.  As such, it will not pull 'blank' data, and does not care whether or not the cells are *actually* merged.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A1, SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($A$1:$A1)*--(LEN($A$1:$A1)>0))) ,1)
```

`$A1` is your target cell.  `$A$1:$A1` will be the cells in-or-above the current row from Column A.  This will expand as you drag the formula down (i.e. on Row 9 it will be `$A$1:$A9`)

The `SUMPRODUCT` will find the `MAX` Row where there is data (`LEN($A1)>0`).The `INDEX` then uses this to return the Value

This in an Array Formula, so you will need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after you type the formula in.

If there is no data in or above, then the formula will reference the top cell, and return 0 (See [this article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/use-formula-evaluate-blank-cell)).  We can return a blank (`""`) by using a `CountA` to see if there is any data:

```
=IF(COUNTA($A$1:$A1)<1, "", INDEX($A$1:$A1, SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($A$1:$A1)*--(LEN($A$1:$A1)>0))),1))
```

Comment: can this be use to retrieve date?

Comment: @inversebow Yes, this will work for any non-blank values.  Try creating several merged cells with different values in Column A of a blank Worksheet, and test the code out.

Comment: the column return '0' when the cell empty. you know why?

Comment: @inversebow If there is no data in-or-above the same row, it will return the value from the top of the column.  If a formula references a blank cell, it will return 0 - this is a known functionality of Excel.  You can get past this with a `CountA` - I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit   

Public Sub MainMethod()

 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    MySubMethod() ' your func

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, just add code before your code (at the start of your main method) and code after your code (at the end of your main method), nothing more.. let me know if it helped with speedUp

Comment: it return "invalid outside procedure" . do you know why?

Comment: @inversebow Are you trying to use the Function in the *Worksheet* as a UDF ("User Defined Function"), instead of in a Macro?  That has a **huge** impact on what you can and can't do, and should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: see my updated code.. it s the whole code in Module1.vb

Comment: @PeterKsenak, Return syntax error. know why?

`Option Explicit

Public Sub MainMethod()

 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    MySubMethod()
    
     Function mergedText(rngMergedCell As Range)
    
     If rngMergedCell.MergeCells = True Then
        mergedText = rngMergedCell.MergeArea(1, 1)
     Else
        mergedText = rngMergedCell
     End If

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub`

Comment: yes I know, you did an incredible ragbag , see that : Option Explicit

Public Sub MainMethod()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

MySubMethod()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub




Function mergedText(rngMergedCell As Range)

If rngMergedCell.MergeCells = True Then
 mergedText = rngMergedCell.MergeArea(1, 1)
Else: mergedText = rngMergedCell

End If

End Function

Comment: I have to remove "MySubMethod()" then only the code works. As for the speed, I let you know after few data input.

Answer (score -1):

This code should do the job, though is not a funcition you only need to run it once everytime you need it and it will be instant delivery.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet") 'change YourSheet for your actual sheet name
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row 'I suppose your last row with actual data will be on column I

        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = .Range("H2:K" & LastRow).Value 'I'm assuming you have headers.

        Dim ValueA As String
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then ValueA = arr(i, 1) 'this will always get the last value from column A not empty cell
            If arr(i, 2) <> 0 Then arr(i, 3) = ValueA & "-" & arr(i, 2) 'if cell I <> 0 then concatenate the values
        Next i

        .Range("H2:K" & LastRow).Value = arr
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the downvote, but I'd appreciate a comment to know what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: Did not downvote, but are you able to explain why you think that this will solve OP's issue?

Comment: He wants to concatenate the value from column 1 and column 2 into column 3, IF: column A is empty must get the previous filled value. Column 2 must be <> to 0. So this code does that.